# how to show toast in WorkManager doWork()

Tags: android-toast, android-workmanager

how to show toast in WorkManager do work()?

When I try, it throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create **Handler** to show Toast on UI thread.

Your `doWork` method will be like:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Log.d(TAG, "doWork for Sync");

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Run your task here
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, 1000 );

    return Result.success();
}
```

Note : `mContext` will be available in Constructor.

Hope it will help you. Thank you.

Comment: the solution works well, but if you need to run it your work on background it will not. Because it requires context, so be aware!

Comment: @NurseyitTursunkulov Context is available inside workers via `getApplicationContext()` anyways so it will work regardless affinity.

Answer (score 0):

Also found alternative solution, worked for me as well:

```
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    context.getMainExecutor().execute(() -> Toast.makeText(context, "Сас ))", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
    return Result.success();   // may be done with handler
}
```

But also i saved `Context` variable to the classfield

```
Context context;

public BackgroundWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    this.context = context;
}
```